# white-space: pre-line for small cell

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have these lines of data, which each of them are defined as `rTableCell` and has a fixed `width: 150px;`. Without using any `white-space`, when a text is longer than this `width`, it will be hidden. I want them to go on the next line and also be centred vertically. I tried using `white-space:pre-line` but having the maximum `height: 39px` the text won't go to the next line. Is there any solution in order to shrink the texts in `height:39px` and having all of it in the existing cell writing in 2 lines?

```css
.rTableCell {
  float: left;
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 36px;
}
.rTableCellId {
  width: 30px;
}
.ndLabel {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
  <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">793</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">Visits on website or Facebook or Google</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">[Web Property]</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
  <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">835</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">Visits on website</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">LP thank you</div>
</div>
```

**Desired behaviour:**

[image: Picture]

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/za21egrf/)

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/b5vhjs8w/?

Comment: @j08691 exactly ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the table-cell and table-row display options to format as you like:

```css
.rTableRow {
  display:table-row;
}
.rTableCell {
  height: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 3%;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:table-cell;
}

.rTableCellId {
  width: 50px;
}

.ndLabel {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
  <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">793</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">Visits on website or Facebook or Google</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">[Web Property]</div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="rTableRow" style="color:#797979">
  <div class="rTableCell rTableCellId ndLabel">835</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">Visits on website</div>
  <div class="rTableCell ndLabel">LP thank you</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the css here

```
.rTableCell {
     float: left;
     height: 36px;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 3px 1%;
     width: 150px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     /*line-height: 36px;*/
     white-space: break-word
}
```